# Why doesn't the metricbeat index name change each day?

Tags: elasticsearch, metricbeat

I am using a metricbeat (7.3) docker container along side several other docker containers, and sending the results to an elasticsearch (7.3) instance.  This works, and the first time everything spins up I get an index in elasticsearch called `metricbeat-7.3.1-2019.09.06-000001`

The initial problem is that I have a Graphana dashboard setup to look for an index with today's date, so it seems to ignore one created several days ago altogether.  I could try to figure out what's wrong with those Grafana queries, but more generically I need those index names to roll at some point - the index that's there is already up to over 1.3GB, and at some point that will just be too big for the system.

My initial metricbeat.yml config:

```
- module: docker
  metricsets:
    - "container"
    - "cpu"
    - "diskio"
    - "memory"
    - "network"
  hosts: ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]
  period: 10s
  enabled: true
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["${ELASTICSEARCH_URL}"]
```

Searching around a bit, it seems like the index field on the elasticsearch output should configure the index name, so I tried the following:

```
- module: docker
  metricsets:
    - "container"
    - "cpu"
    - "diskio"
    - "memory"
    - "network"
  hosts: ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]
  period: 10s
  enabled: true
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["${ELASTICSEARCH_URL}"]
  index: "metricbeat-%{[beat.version]}-instance1-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
```

That throws an error about needing setup.template settings, so I settled on this:

```
- module: docker
  metricsets:
    - "container"
    - "cpu"
    - "diskio"
    - "memory"
    - "network"
  hosts: ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]
  period: 10s
  enabled: true
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["${ELASTICSEARCH_URL}"]
  index: "metricbeat-%{[beat.version]}-instance1-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
setup.template:
  overwrite: true
  name: "metricbeat"
  pattern: "metricbeat-*"
```

I don't really know what the setup.template section does, so most of that is a guess from Google searches.

I'm not really sure if the issue is on the metricbeat side, or on the elasticsearch side, or somewhere in-between.  But bottom line - how do I get them to roll the index to a new one when the day changes?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: There is no error message.  The beat messages are getting delivered, but only to the first index that gets created.  The index name never rolls over to the next day.

Comment: Any solutions to this? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the setting/steps that worked for me:

**metricbeat.yml** file:

```
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["<es-ip>:9200"]
  index: metricbeat-%{[beat.version]}
  index_pattern: -%{+yyyy.MM.dd}
  ilm.enabled: true
```

then, over to kibana i.e :5601:

[image]

go to "Stack Monitoring", select the "metricbeat-*"

do this kind of a setting to begin with, and what follows later is self-explanatory too:

[image]